# Unity - "Unrecognized escape sequence"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a really annoying error, I made a stopwatch in unity and this error keep showing up...
Here's the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class StopWatch : MonoBehaviour
{
    float currentTime;   
    public Text currentTimeText; 

    void Start()
    {
        currentTime = 0;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        currentTime = currentTime + Time.deltaTime;
        TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(currentTime);
        currentTimeText.text = time.ToString("@mm\:ss\:fff");
    }
}
```

I don't know what to do, Im new to C#. Thank you! :)

Comment: Hi ! I'm pretty sure it's because you put *@* inside the quotes, it should be just before like this `time.ToString(@"mm\:ss\:fff")`

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now.

Comment: Hey @derHugo! Okay, I will next time. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change:

```
currentTimeText.text = time.ToString("@mm\:ss\:fff");
```

to:

```
currentTimeText.text = time.ToString(@"mm\:ss\:fff");
```

or:

```
currentTimeText.text = time.ToString("mm\\:ss\\:fff");
```